# Getting MediaWiki notifications for all changes

Tags: mediawiki

Some users would like to get notifications of changes to a relatively small MediaWiki instance. RSS feeds are not ideal for a number of reasons.

My ideal would be a daily (or configurable period) mail of all changes that have been made. Features I am looking for include

- batching of changes to a single page during the period (often a page changes a number of times and you don't need to know every blow by blow change
- including by category
- excluding by specific  categories

Is there any such solution (maybe a plugin or standalone program) that can be recommended? I am an administrator of the wiki and sysadmin of its hosting machine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are an admin of this wiki, you can add

```
$wgUsersNotifiedOnAllChanges = array( 'UserName' );
```

into LocalSettings.php and get all possible notifications.

Answer (score 2):

MediaWiki has [email notification built in](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Configuration_settings#Email_notification_.28Enotif.29_settings).

With [the CategoryWatch extension](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:CategoryWatch) you can watch pages in a particular category and get emailed on changes.

I don't know any way to batch changes (other than excluding minor changes) or exclude specific categories.